# Wordpress live validation form plugin

Tags: wordpress

I want a live validation form plugin for wordpress. In a page I have fields for Firstname, Lastname, Compnay name, Mobile number. I want to validate all of them without clicking on submit button. So is there any kind of worpress plugin available? Any help will be appreciable.

Comment: Search for validation onBlur and onFocus instead of live validation. You might find a plugin but ideally you can do this with jquery validation plugin and small javascript code on your page where the form is. Plugin is an overkill unless you have forms on all pages.

Answer (score 1):

Add [jquery.validate](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) to a plugin or theme, and you can write simple validation scripts that will do what you want. I don't know if there is a plugin wrapping that up.

Alternatively, buy and install [Gravity Forms](http://www.gravityforms.com/), which will do something similar, and is a great way to build forms.